# How to filter keys in record_path in pandas json_normalize method?

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have a large json/dict:

```
{
      "vegetarian": false,
      "vegan": false,
      "glutenFree": false,
      "dairyFree": false,
      "veryHealthy": false,
      "cheap": false,
      "veryPopular": false,
      "sustainable": false,
      "weightWatcherSmartPoints": 14,
      "gaps": "no",
      "lowFodmap": false,
      "aggregateLikes": 1,
      "spoonacularScore": 57.0,
      "healthScore": 21.0,
      "creditsText": "BBC Good Food",
      "sourceName": "BBC Good Food",
      "pricePerServing": 231.2,
      "id": 1089577,
      "title": "Hungarian Goulash Stew",
      "readyInMinutes": 120,
      "servings": 4,
      "sourceUrl": "https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/1107653/hungarian-goulash-stew",
      "image": "https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/1089577-312x231.jpg",
      "imageType": "jpg",
      "nutrition": {
        "nutrients": [
          {
            "name": "Calories",
            "title": "Calories",
            "amount": 323.18,
            "unit": "kcal",
            "percentOfDailyNeeds": 16.16
          },
          {
            "name": "Fat",
            "title": "Fat",
            "amount": 15.14,
            "unit": "g",
            "percentOfDailyNeeds": 23.3
          },
          {
            "name": "Saturated Fat",
            "title": "Saturated Fat",
            "amount": 4.43,
            "unit": "g",
            "percentOfDailyNeeds": 27.69
          },
          {
            "name": "Carbohydrates",
            "title": "Carbohydrates",
            "amount": 38.95,
            "unit": "g",
            "percentOfDailyNeeds": 12.98
          },
          {
            "name": "Net Carbohydrates",
            "title": "Net Carbohydrates",
            "amount": 34.64,
            "unit": "g",
            "percentOfDailyNeeds": 12.6
          },
          {
            "name": "Sugar",
            "title": "Sugar",
            "amount": 11.27,
            "unit": "g",
            "percentOfDailyNeeds": 12.52
          },
          {
            "name": "Cholesterol",
            "title": "Cholesterol",
            "amount": 102.67,
            "unit": "mg",
            "percentOfDailyNeeds": 34.22
          },
          {
            "name": "Sodium",
            "title": "Sodium",
            "amount": 1864.24,
            "unit": "mg",
            "percentOfDailyNeeds": 81.05
          },
          {
            "name": "Protein",
            "title": "Protein",
            "amount": 10.3,
            "unit": "g",
            "percentOfDailyNeeds": 20.6
          },
          {
            "name": "Vitamin A",
            "title": "Vitamin A",
            "amount": 3866.5,
            "unit": "IU",
            "percentOfDailyNeeds": 77.33
          },
          {
            "name": "Vitamin E",
            "title": "Vitamin E",
            "amount": 3.49,
            "unit": "mg",
            "percentOfDailyNeeds": 23.3
          },
          {
            "name": "Selenium",
            "title": "Selenium",
            "amount": 13.41,
            "unit": "µg",
            "percentOfDailyNeeds": 19.16
          },
          {
            "name": "Manganese",
            "title": "Manganese",
            "amount": 0.38,
            "unit": "mg",
            "percentOfDailyNeeds": 18.83
          },
          {
            "name": "Iron",
            "title": "Iron",
            "amount": 3.19,
            "unit": "mg",
            "percentOfDailyNeeds": 17.74
          },
          {
            "name": "Vitamin B2",
            "title": "Vitamin B2",
            "amount": 0.3,
            "unit": "mg",
            "percentOfDailyNeeds": 17.54
          },
          {
            "name": "Fiber",
            "title": "Fiber",
            "amount": 4.31,
            "unit": "g",
            "percentOfDailyNeeds": 17.22
          },
          {
            "name": "Folate",
            "title": "Folate",
            "amount": 61.04,
            "unit": "µg",
            "percentOfDailyNeeds": 15.26
          },
          {
            "name": "Vitamin B6",
            "title": "Vitamin B6",
            "amount": 0.3,
            "unit": "mg",
            "percentOfDailyNeeds": 14.9
          },
          {
            "name": "Vitamin B1",
            "title": "Vitamin B1",
            "amount": 0.21,
            "unit": "mg",
            "percentOfDailyNeeds": 13.72
          },
          {
            "name": "Vitamin K",
            "title": "Vitamin K",
            "amount": 13.78,
            "unit": "µg",
            "percentOfDailyNeeds": 13.13
          },
          {
            "name": "Potassium",
            "title": "Potassium",
            "amount": 407.99,
            "unit": "mg",
            "percentOfDailyNeeds": 11.66
          },
          {
            "name": "Vitamin C",
            "title": "Vitamin C",
            "amount": 9.53,
            "unit": "mg",
            "percentOfDailyNeeds": 11.56
          },
          {
            "name": "Phosphorus",
            "title": "Phosphorus",
            "amount": 111.88,
            "unit": "mg",
            "percentOfDailyNeeds": 11.19
          },
          {
            "name": "Vitamin B3",
            "title": "Vitamin B3",
            "amount": 2.01,
            "unit": "mg",
            "percentOfDailyNeeds": 10.05
          },
          {
            "name": "Copper",
            "title": "Copper",
            "amount": 0.15,
            "unit": "mg",
            "percentOfDailyNeeds": 7.53
          },
          {
            "name": "Magnesium",
            "title": "Magnesium",
            "amount": 29.73,
            "unit": "mg",
            "percentOfDailyNeeds": 7.43
          },
          {
            "name": "Vitamin B5",
            "title": "Vitamin B5",
            "amount": 0.69,
            "unit": "mg",
            "percentOfDailyNeeds": 6.95
          },
          {
            "name": "Zinc",
            "title": "Zinc",
            "amount": 0.89,
            "unit": "mg",
            "percentOfDailyNeeds": 5.93
          },
          {
            "name": "Calcium",
            "title": "Calcium",
            "amount": 58.6,
            "unit": "mg",
            "percentOfDailyNeeds": 5.86
          },
          {
            "name": "Vitamin B12",
            "title": "Vitamin B12",
            "amount": 0.2,
            "unit": "µg",
            "percentOfDailyNeeds": 3.3
          },
          {
            "name": "Vitamin D",
            "title": "Vitamin D",
            "amount": 0.46,
            "unit": "µg",
            "percentOfDailyNeeds": 3.06
          }
        ]
}
```

I would like to keep the `id`, `readyInMinutes` and `title` keys + `nutrition`, the issue is that I need the nutrition to be parsed (because it's a list of dicts).

I am trying panda's `pd.json_normalize` function to do this:

```
keys = ['id', 'title', 'readyInMinutes']

pd.json_normalize(results[0], meta = keys, record_path=['nutrition',['nutrients']], record_prefix='nutrients.')
```

But if I need to filter which keys I want inside the record_path? For example only `title` and `amount`?
Please instruct how can I configure it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To parse JSON data you can use [JMESPath](https://jmespath.org/) library.

JMESPath search syntax:

```
search(<jmespath expr>, <JSON document>)
```

In your case the JMESPath expression will be this:

```
{id: id, readyInMinutes:readyInMinutes, title: title, nutrition: {nutrients: nutrition.nutrients[*].{title: title, amount: amount}}}
```

Output:

```
{
  "id": 1089577,
  "readyInMinutes": 120,
  "title": "Hungarian Goulash Stew",
  "nutrition": {
    "nutrients": [
      {
        "title": "Calories",
        "amount": 323.18
      },
      {
        "title": "Fat",
        "amount": 15.14
      },
      {
        "title": "Saturated Fat",
        "amount": 4.43
      },
      {
        "title": "Carbohydrates",
        "amount": 38.95
      },
      {
        "title": "Net Carbohydrates",
        "amount": 34.64
      },
      {
        "title": "Sugar",
        "amount": 11.27
      },
      {
        "title": "Cholesterol",
        "amount": 102.67
      },
      {
        "title": "Sodium",
        "amount": 1864.24
      },
      {
        "title": "Protein",
        "amount": 10.3
      },
      {
        "title": "Vitamin A",
        "amount": 3866.5
      },
      {
        "title": "Vitamin E",
        "amount": 3.49
      },
      {
        "title": "Selenium",
        "amount": 13.41
      },
      {
        "title": "Manganese",
        "amount": 0.38
      },
      {
        "title": "Iron",
        "amount": 3.19
      },
      {
        "title": "Vitamin B2",
        "amount": 0.3
      },
      {
        "title": "Fiber",
        "amount": 4.31
      },
      {
        "title": "Folate",
        "amount": 61.04
      },
      {
        "title": "Vitamin B6",
        "amount": 0.3
      },
      {
        "title": "Vitamin B1",
        "amount": 0.21
      },
      {
        "title": "Vitamin K",
        "amount": 13.78
      },
      {
        "title": "Potassium",
        "amount": 407.99
      },
      {
        "title": "Vitamin C",
        "amount": 9.53
      },
      {
        "title": "Phosphorus",
        "amount": 111.88
      },
      {
        "title": "Vitamin B3",
        "amount": 2.01
      },
      {
        "title": "Copper",
        "amount": 0.15
      },
      {
        "title": "Magnesium",
        "amount": 29.73
      },
      {
        "title": "Vitamin B5",
        "amount": 0.69
      },
      {
        "title": "Zinc",
        "amount": 0.89
      },
      {
        "title": "Calcium",
        "amount": 58.6
      },
      {
        "title": "Vitamin B12",
        "amount": 0.2
      },
      {
        "title": "Vitamin D",
        "amount": 0.46
      }
    ]
  }
}
```